# Evaluating the tensor product many times for a given list

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors

I need to evaluate the tensor product 10 times in a given list( {g,e,r})

Here I have evaluated for 3 times...

```
#\[TensorProduct]#\[TensorProduct]#&[{g,e,r}]
..
..
```

Evaluated for 6 times...

```
#\[TensorProduct]#\[TensorProduct]#\[TensorProduct]#\[TensorProduct]#\[TensorProduct]#&[{g,e,r}] (*n=6*)
```

Each time I need to include the tensor product on the list. Is there any better way to do this for large no.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the chained function on-the-fly for each `n`:

```
ClearAll@chainTensorProduct
chainTensorProduct[list_, n_Integer] := Function[TensorProduct @@ ConstantArray[#, n]]@list
```

Example:

```
#\[TensorProduct]#\[TensorProduct]#&[{g, e, r}] == chainTensorProduct[{g, e, r}, 3]
(* True *)
```